# automatic mount any external drive under /media with read/write access to everyone

Tags: mount, external-hdd, automount

Here is my issue:

My computer has 4 USB ports and is running Ubuntu 12.10. I receive different USBs every day, plug to my computer, **read/write** data to them, and then send them away.

What I want is to automatically mount any USB I plug into my computer. The first detected USB will go to `/media/HDD1`, the second will go to `/media/HDD2` and so on.
Or it would be great if USB plugged to port1 will go to `/media/HDD1`, USB plugged to port2 will go to `/media/HDD2`, and so on.

The path `/media` is not important but I would like the HDD1-4 directories in one place so that I can easily access them.

The USBs are normally ext2 but sometimes I get FAT32, NTFS USBs as well.

I also want USB to be mounted without logging in to Ubuntu as I often access `/media/HDD..` from another Windows computer.

How can I do that? What change in `udev` rules, `fstab` should I make? Any suggestion is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, here we can use the same trick that `fstab` uses for Optical media (aka CD's and DVD's):

```
/dev/sr0        /media/cdrom0   udf,iso9660 user,noauto     0       0
```

The first column indicates the file system, I'm sure your USB's will have fixed values, so lets presume that everything after `sda` is a USB, and since you can only have 4 USB's at the same time, the list goes from `sdb`, `sdc`, `sdd` and `sde`.

```
$ ls /dev/sd*
/dev/sda   /dev/sdb   /dev/sdb3  /dev/sdb6  /dev/sdc  /dev/sdf
/dev/sda1  /dev/sdb1  /dev/sdb4  /dev/sdb7  /dev/sdd
/dev/sda2  /dev/sdb2  /dev/sdb5  /dev/sdb8  /dev/sde
```

<sub>(In my case I use a memory reader, so my USB drivers start from `sdg` but lets continue.)</sub>

Now, we assume each USB have one and only **one** partition, so the lines we need, for our `fstab`, are:

```
/dev/sdb1
/dev/sdc1
/dev/sdd1
/dev/sde1
```

Then you said your mount points has to be fixed, so after you have created your directories, lets add them:

```
/dev/sdb1 /media/HDD1
/dev/sdc1 /media/HDD2
/dev/sdd1 /media/HDD3
/dev/sde1 /media/HDD4
```

Since you can have almost all type of file systems, lets use the `auto` so fstab guess the file type to use:

```
/dev/sdb1 /media/HDD1 auto
/dev/sdc1 /media/HDD2 auto
/dev/sdd1 /media/HDD3 auto
/dev/sde1 /media/HDD4 auto
```

Ok, now lets boil down to the options, which will be the very same for CD's with the plus of read/write permissions:

```
/dev/sdb1 /media/HDD1 auto rw,users,noauto,allow_other,umask=0
/dev/sdc1 /media/HDD2 auto rw,users,noauto,allow_other,umask=0
/dev/sde1 /media/HDD3 auto rw,users,noauto,allow_other,umask=0
/dev/sde1 /media/HDD4 auto rw,users,noauto,allow_other,umask=0
```

`rw` tells that we want read and write permission, `users` allows any user to mount a device, `noauto` prevents that the driver gets mounted automatically when `mount -a` is called, like it does at boot, preventing boot ERRORS and WARNINGS, `allow_other` allows other but the user that mounted the driver to have the same permissions, and `umask=0` prevents the defaults umask from being applied.

Now the only 2 left fields are pretty much just about the `dump` order and `fsck` order, which could be in `0` both, leaving us with the final result:

```
/dev/sdb1 /media/HDD1 auto rw,user,noauto,allow_other 0 0
/dev/sdc1 /media/HDD2 auto rw,user,noauto,allow_other 0 0
/dev/sdd1 /media/HDD3 auto rw,user,noauto,allow_other 0 0
/dev/sde1 /media/HDD4 auto rw,user,noauto,allow_other 0 0
```

With this, each time that you plug a USB device it will being automagically mounted in the mount point without the intervention of the user. You should modify according to your necessities.

Comment: thank Braiam. I'm not sure if changing fstab can automatically mount USBs without the need of reboot or using "mount" command. I found a simple solution of using autofs. Not only does it automount but also supports auto-unmount after pre-defined time of no action, which is very useful in my case

Comment: No, it doesn't. As I said at the beginning, I was using the same trick fstab uses for CD/DVD that don't require the use of `root` nor `mount` nor restart.

Answer (score 3):

Here is the solution I found:

Firstly I install autofs on my linux PC:

```
sudo apt-get install autofs
```

It will create auto.master file under `/etc/auto.master`

Add the following line at the end of that file:

```
/media/mount /etc/auto.mount --timeout=10 --ghost
```

`/media/mount` is a directory where I want to mount all external drives into. `/etc/auto.mount` is the file to put in mounting rules. `--timeout=10` means it will automatically unmount the drive after 10 sec of inactivity. `--ghost` means it still leaves a picture of content when it is unmounted. Change this line according to your needs.

Edit the `/etc/auto.mount` file and add the following lines:

```
disk1  -fstype=auto,sync  :/dev/sdc1
disk2  -fstype=auto,sync  :/dev/sdd1
disk3  -fstype=auto,sync  :/dev/sde1
disk4  -fstype=auto,sync  :/dev/sdf1
disk5  -fstype=auto,sync  :/dev/sdg1
disk6  -fstype=auto,sync  :/dev/sdh1
disk7  -fstype=auto,sync  :/dev/sdi1
disk8  -fstype=auto,sync  :/dev/sdj1
DVD    -fstype=iso9660,ro :/dev/sr0
```

For normal drives such as USB or eSATA set `-fstype=auto,sync`. I have 8 USB+eSATA ports so I declare 8 mount points here. My PC already has `sda` and `sdb` as local disks so I put `sdc1` -> `sdj1` for external devices. They are actually device nodes in `/dev` when you plug your drives in.
An exception of mounting rule is DVD mounting as you see above.

When I insert any drives they will show up as disk1, disk2, ... under `/media/mount` directory, and will auto-unmount after 10 seconds. I don't need to touch my PC and can access it from somewhere else (such as Virtual machine)