# My Ubuntu is running fsck on every bootup

Tags: boot, fsck

On every bootup it's the same:

```
/dev/sda1: clean, 908443/38690816 files, 44176803/154733312 blocks
```

Is it some kind of option Ubuntu uses to ensure filesystem consistency or is there something wrong with my HDD? `fsck` takes up to 30s while booting and so about triples the time needed otherwise.

Full output (partly in German):

```
Begin: Loading essential drivers ... done.
Begin: Running /scripts/init-premount ... done.
Begin: Mounting root file system ... Begin: Running /scripts/local-top ... done.
Begin: Running /scripts/local-premount ... done.
Begin: Running /scripts/local-bottom ... done.
done.
Begin: Running /scripts/init-bottom ... done.
fsck von util-linux 2.20.1
/dev/sda1: sauber, 908443/38690816 Dateien, 44176803/154733312 Blöcke
udevd[623]: unknown key 'SYSFS{idVendor}' in /lib/udev/rules.d/45-libticables.rules:6

udevd[623]: invalid rule '/lib/udev/rules.d/45-libticables.rules:6'

 * Starting mDNS/DNS-SD daemon                                                 [ OK ]
 * Starting Reload cups, upon starting avahi-daemon to make sure remote queues are populated                                                                   [ OK ]
 * Starting configure network device security                                  [ OK ]
 * Starting bluetooth daemon                                                   [ OK ]
 ####* Starting all other stuff
```

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you running?  Does your system shutdown cleanly?

Comment: Raring x64 = 13.04 64bit. Shutdown runs cleanly as far as I can say (Where's the shutdown logfile?)

Comment: fsck says it *didn't* run, that the volume was clean.

Comment: But the checking component has to run in order to say it is clean, doesn't it?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

> /dev/sda1: clean, 908443/38690816 Files, 44176803/154733312 Blocks

The line producing that message is [this](https://github.com/tytso/e2fsprogs/blob/master/e2fsck/unix.c#L433):

```
/* Print the summary message when we're skipping a full check */
log_out(ctx, _("%s: clean, %u/%u files, %llu/%llu blocks"),
```

It skips the "full check" but just made sure that some fast test to the journal are clean and there isn't orphan inodes:

```
cat /var/log/boot.log 
fsck from util-linux 2.20.1
fsck from util-linux 2.20.1
/dev/sda1: clean, 260598/771552 files, 1684682/3080192 blocks
/dev/sdb10: recovering journal
/dev/sdb10: Clearing orphaned inode 142568 (uid=1000, gid=1000, mode=0100664, size=32768)
/dev/sdb10: Clearing orphaned inode 138527 (uid=1000, gid=1000, mode=0100600, size=9580)
/dev/sdb10: clean, 54957/991232 files, 3498365/3958006 blocks
```

This is normal and expected. If it was a real thorough check it would take much more time but it usually takes a second or less. Systemd `systemd-fsck(8)` manual page has the conditions where a full check is triggered:

> systemd-fsck-root.service is responsible for file system checks on the
>      root file system, but only if the root filesystem was not checked
>   in    the initramfs.  systemd-fsck@.service is used for all other file
>   systems and for the root file system in the initramfs.
>
> These services are started at boot if passno in /etc/fstab for the
>   file    system is set to a value greater than zero. The file system
>   check for    root is performed before the other file systems. Other
>   file systems may    be checked in parallel, except when they are on
>   the same rotating disk.
>
> systemd-fsck does not know any details about specific filesystems,
>   and    simply executes file system checkers specific to each
>   filesystem type    (/sbin/fsck.*). **This helper will decide if the
>   filesystem should    actually be checked based on the time since last
>   check, number of    mounts, unclean unmount, etc.**

You can simply check that the tests took next to nothing to run (if you use systemd):

```
sudo systemd-analyze blame | grep fsck
          1.608s systemd-fsck@dev-disk-by\x2duuid-408535fe\x2d28e6\x2d4d82\x2dbb59\x2d9810ead089a3.service
            87ms systemd-fsck@dev-mapper-vlhome\x2dlvhome.service
```

Comment: An answer to the q at your link says you can control the behavior by modifying `/etc/fstab`. Is it only possible to set `0` or `1` or can I tell my system when to perform this "fast" test?

Comment: @the_Seppi no, you can't deactivate the fsck in the fstab but the order, [this other answer of mine](http://askubuntu.com/a/328637/169736) explains it, just read it about the end of it.

Comment: I read that changing the last digit to 0 disables fsck on mount

Comment: @the_Seppi yeah, you are right, `1` and `2` determine the order to be checked but `0` or none says that it doesn't need. But then I have both values in 0 and still get the check.

Comment: I tried setting 0. Now the fsck isnt appearing any more, but theres still a 25s pause. And its saying "recoverz required on ro filesystem". I just changed it back for this concerns me...

Comment: @the_Seppi apparently then your system either is dirty/failling or you have the `/forceck` file in your root directory. I would boot as recovery mode, run fsck then remove the file if it exist.

Comment: I can't boot into recovery for GRUB doesn't show up on hitting shift... Instead I created `/forcefsck`. On reboot it told me it was performing fsck. However, the recovery required still appears and both files in `/var/log/fsck/` say "nochting logged yet"

Comment: @the_Seppi as I said, my Debian always do that even in cold boot, so I presume Ubuntu is doing the same, but be aware that the test isn't complete/exaustive.

Comment: There is a bug reported on launchpad: [upstart bug #1504688](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/upstart/+bug/1504688) .
It contains a possible solution in [comment #17](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/upstart/+bug/1504688/comments/17).

Comment: @azurkin there's no "bug", there's no "problem". The message is harmless and happens on most debian-based systems.

Comment: @Braiam i know that it is not a bug. I called it a bug, only because it is reported on bugs.launchpad.net :)
But I don't think that all ubuntu users must see such message on every boot after a splash screen.
I found this question while searching for information about this message, because I didn't know if it was ok or not to see it.

Comment: @Braiam any excessive output while linux was told "quiet splash" should be considered a bug. Checking FS state b4 booting is for greater good, yes. Displaying meaningless "everything is OK" message, interrupting the splash screen is NOT!

Comment: @mekkanizer is not "excessive output", not by any metric. Everything is doing exactly as it should.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure it is fsck that is taking 30s and not just that the next console message relating to udevd takes 30 seconds? In other words, maybe the udevd is taking 30 seconds to timeout working on the libticables thing before showing a console message?

Try removing (or moving someplace else temporarily)

```
/lib/udev/rules.d/45-libticables.rules
```

and see if that helps.

Comment: No it's definitely fsck. The `Running /scripts/init-bottom ...done` is printed at about 3s, the fsck-clean at about 30s.

Comment: What type of filesystem are you using?

Comment: I am using EXT4

Comment: Is the pause before it prints "fsck von ..." or before "/dev/sda..."?

Comment: Where are you mounting /dev/sda1? You might try adding: `noauto,x-systemd.automount` to the fstab options if it's /home or something.  So the system will skip mounting until it is acessed as per: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Systemd#Automount

Comment: `/dev/sda1` is the system partition mounted at `/`

Answer (score 0):

This fsck on every boot happened to me due to bad clock. It appears that systemd-fsck@ runs before systemd-timesyncd, and without a battery-backed RTC, the system time is wrong at the time fsck is run.

I confirmed that this is indeed what triggers the full check (instead of having fsck exit quickly), by disabling systemd-timesynd, setting clock to the pre-sync value found in journalctl, and running fsck. The e2fsck then proceeds to do a full check, once it detects that the last superblock write time is in the future:

```
fsck from util-linux 2.29.2
e2fsck 1.43.4 (31-Jan-2017)
Superblock last write time (Mon Jun 19 00:48:11 2017,
    now = Tue Jan 31 20:09:28 2017) is in the future.
Fix<y>? yes
Pass 1: Checking inodes, blocks, and sizes
...
```

Note that, this trigger for the full check is unrelated to the other triggers of max mount count and time interval since last check, seen in `dumpe2fs -h`, mentioned in other answers here.

Note that, without setting the clock (that is, letting timesyncd sync it), fsck will not do a full check, but will exit quickly with a 'filesystem clean' message.

As a workaround, I disabled fsck in /etc/fstab by setting 'pass' field to 0. Eventually, I'll buy a battery backed RTC for this device.

Answer (score -1):

My searches land me conclusion that Ubuntu default maximum mount count is set to -1. This means that fsck will never run on any boot regardless of number of mounts. You can check yours by command -

```
sudo dumpe2fs -h /dev/sda8 | grep -i 'mount count'
```

You can increase it on your requirement using `tune2fs`. A typical example is as follows -

```
sudo tune2fs -c 30 -i 1w /dev/sda8
```

Customise it on your accord.

Comment: No, that means the value will be disreagrded by the kernel and e2fsck: http://linux.die.net/man/8/tune2fs "If max-mount-counts is 0 or -1, the number of times the filesystem is mounted will be disregarded by e2fsck(8) and the kernel."

Comment: My bad, will change post.