# An unexpected message appears while booting Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: boot

The full message is:

> /dev/sda2: clean, 201776/60878736 files, 4991277/243040256 blocks

My PC is an Asus FX50J, whose video card is a NVidia Geforce GTX 850M.

What should I do to solve the problem?

Comment: That's not a problem or an exception, but the result of the disk check performed at boot.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [My Ubuntu is running fsck on every bootup](http://askubuntu.com/questions/383114/my-ubuntu-is-running-fsck-on-every-bootup)

Answer (score 2):

You need to do ... nothing, thats perfectly fine, this message should normaly be invisible but somehow it snuck to visbility.

It just tells you that there are no orphaned nodes and that your journal is clean.

Comment: How to make it invisible?

Comment: @ecoart I would have written it if I'd know this :)

Comment: `this message should normaly be invisible` Should it, though? I run Debian and always see it. ...which I consider a good thing.