# Can't get lubuntu to boot

Tags: boot, nvidia, lubuntu

One of my Pentium 4 HT machines is slow all the time with Windows XP, so I unplugged the drive with Windows on it and put a 160GB hard drive in there and burned Minimal Lubuntu to a CD (only version of Ubuntu I could fit onto a 700MB CD). Installation went pretty smoothly.

However, now when I start the PC up, it goes through BIOS stuff and it shows the Ubuntu 16.04 loading screen and takes a minute or so to load.

Afterwards however the screen goes black and in the top corner I get...

> /dev/sda1: clean, 57315/9740288 files, 913160/38941440 blocks

Nothing else displays on the screen. I left it like this for about half an hour today as I found a post that said it was a standard check but the thing hasn't budged since. I have seen a few forum posts online saying it's a video driver issue.

This is my first time really trying to put Linux on a computer for use, so if there is a solution to this, please explain it to me like I'm 5 years old.

Thanks

P.S.

PC is running a 2.80GHz Pentium 4 with Hyper-threading, 512MB RAM and an FX 5200 GeForce card. GMA 915 onboard produces blank screen after bios when I encountered this problem.

Comment: If your GRUB menu doesn't come up automatically, press SHIFT when your computer starts booting (try holding or pressing repeatedly) and then press E on your keyboard to edit the boot.  Remove `quiet splash` and then press F10 to boot.  It should now show you everything it does when booting, and you should see what the holdup is and where it's stalling.

Answer (score 0):

Check out: [My Ubuntu is running fsck on every bootup](https://askubuntu.com/questions/383114/my-ubuntu-is-running-fsck-on-every-bootup)

Seems that there is a graphics related issue.  If your PC has a built-in graphics, I think the 915 has a VGA port on it, then try to boot with that first.

There's some additional flags you can enable, but try that quick test and see what you get.  If you can boot then you can start to look at the FX5200 as a possible source of the issues on boot.

Comment: Removed the FX 5200 and hooked up the monitor to the integrated gpu. Computer POSTS and takes much longer to load but ends up showing the same blank screen with /dev/sda1: ect.