# Ubuntu 20.04 no longer boots, connects to internet after bad shutdown

Tags: boot, networking, internet

My Ubuntu workstation was frozen, so I used the power button to shut it down.

Next time I booted, it displays this message and remains on a black screen with nothing but this message:
`/dev/sdb1: clean, 215539/15237120 files, 3398675/60918272 blocks`

From here (using some other answers I found on this forum, such as [Booting problem after upgrade, /dev/sda2 clean](https://askubuntu.com/questions/809648/booting-problem-after-upgrade-dev-sda2-clean)) I managed to login to the command line (no desktop) with Alt+F1 or Alt+F2 (is there a difference?).

All the suggestions in the threads I found involved updating or reinstalling certain packages (note: I'm using Intel onboard graphics, not a Nvidia GPU. And the integrated graphics was working just fine prior to this, there have been no hardware changes whatsoever), but I am now having an internet connection issue where the machine is unable to connect and just gives a bunch of "Temporary failure in name resolution" errors.

I can replicate this with `ping google.com`, which returns the error message `ping: google.com: Temporary failure in name resolution`.

One thing I've tried was editing my `/etc/resolv.conf` file and adding the line `nameserver 8.8.8.8` following the instructions here: https://www.tecmint.com/resolve-temporary-failure-in-name-resolution/ . Not only did this not work, but after a reboot the file reverted to what it was before.

I'm completely at a loss here: I'm unable to boot to the desktop, and I can't connect to any internet sources to update packages, which seems to be the only solution for the boot issue. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You should check and correct the file system from a live session.

Comment: @ChanganAuto thanks, I'm not sure how to do that? When I run `sudo fsck /dev/sdb` I get an error message `/dev/sdb is in use. e2fsck: Cannot continue, aborting.`

Comment: That why I said *from a live session*...

Comment: @ChanganAuto thanks I'll go figure out what that is and how to do it. Probably in a different question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reinstalled OS. No other suggestions worked.