# How to hide clean message of fsck on startup?

Tags: dual-boot, startup, burg

I have seen that many Ubuntu user feel that clean message makes them feel like error in their system due to this ->

```
/dev/sda3: clean, 291272/4292608 files, 480345/18174432 blocks
```

Since it is not any type of problem indication to system. So, I was thinking that how can we hide it ?

I am on Ubuntu 16.04 using burg to dual boot with Windows 10.

This message was not appeared until I switched to burg. So, it might be something with burg. Hiding it makes Ubuntu look cool and I wish to make it look cooler than any other operating system.

As this question is tagged that it is duplicate of that question, it is not. I am not trying to stop fsck run on every boot. Moreover I want to hide it, as title says. Any ideas.

Comment: Does it really bother you that much?

Comment: First what make you or anyone else feel that is a problem ? Hide the message how ? message during boot ? when and where are you seeing this message ?

Comment: That question is a duplicate and has an answer here - http://askubuntu.com/questions/383114/my-ubuntu-is-running-fsck-on-every-bootup . Why are you asking again ? Please clarify your question.

Comment: Because there is no way said to hide this message. It just says that don't worry.

Comment: As far as I can see there is a way of disabling fsck as the only easy option. You can either file a feature request or you would likely need to write a custom initrd - http://blog.bodhizazen.net/linux/initramfs/

Comment: I tend to agree.  This is a desktop OS.  Normal operation should be silent.  It doesn't bother me personally, but I do assist normal users and they do perceive it as "a possible problem".  It also gives a feeling of lack of polish and QA.

Comment: "This message was not appeared until I switched to burg. So, it might be something with burg." Nope. It is part of "systemd" that got introduced with 16.04.