# I am getting this error when I try to boot my system

Tags: dual-boot

```
dev/sda5:%20clean,1538857/37347328%20files,%2013595168/149369856%20blocks
```

I'm getting that error when I boot my system.

Comment: Please help me to solve

Comment: That is not an error.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [My Ubuntu is running fsck on every bootup](https://askubuntu.com/questions/383114/my-ubuntu-is-running-fsck-on-every-bootup) If it happens every time, but your system does boot, then that should address this. If it doesn't happen every time, then as answered here, it's not a problem at all. If your system doesn't boot, then that's its own problem, and *most likely* not even related to that message, even if that message is the last thing you see. I recommend you **[edit]** this to clarify if there is any problem besides that message (which isn't a problem).

Answer (score 3):

That is not an error. It is perfectly normal. Does your system boot? If it does not, then it is another problem that needs to be investigated.